# Using extern monitor with multitouch to control pc - which cabel to use?

Tags: display, external-display, touch

I have NEC MultiSync V321 monitor to testing and I want connect it to my notebook. I have hdmi cabel and display is fine but I can't control it. So I am asking if somebody knows that I must do some settings to get it working or I must have one more cabel for "transfering" controls from extern monitor? Thanks

Edit: I get another monitor in wrong box. I get V-Touch 3210 OU in box from MultiSync V321 and I searching for solution for V321. So I can't see in manuals that there is USB connector then I saw it so I connected throught it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think NEC MultiSync V321 has NO TOUCH features!

Comment: Yea, you're right. I edited my question.